# Tokenizing words of a sentence in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to tokenize a sentence into words separated only by single space.
I need to get words from the sentence and then write them onto subscribed array.
Here is my work:

```
void writeToStrArrayOneByOne(char words[10][20], char *sentence){

       char *tokenPtr;
       int j = 0;
       int a,i;
       tokenPtr = strtok(sentence," ");

       while(tokenPtr != NULL){


          a = strlen(tokenPtr);

          for(i=0;i<a;i++){

                words[j][i] = tokenPtr[i];
          }
          tokenPtr = strtok(NULL," ");
          j++;

       }
```

And I call the function with only this in order to debug from main :

```
     char words[10][20];
     char *sentence = "this is a token";
     writeToStrArrayOneByOne(words,sentence);
```

However it freezes like when it does when it's EOF exception.
Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok()` modifies the string it's passed.  You're giving it a string literal which cannot be modified.

Try:

```
char sentence[] = "this is a token";
```

Which will make `sentence` a modifiable array of characters.

Also keep in mind that the loop where you copy the tokens won't put a null terminator at the end of each entry - I suspect that you'll probably want those. Maybe try:

```
strcpy(words[j], tokenPtr);
```

Other things you should think about include:

- handling tokens that might be too long
- getting a string with too many tokens
- what needs to be done if there is more than one space between tokens - `strtok()` doesn't deal with that if it matters to you (I mention this only because in your question you specifically mention that tokens are "separated only by a single space")

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe this could help you:

```
char** split (char* string, const char* delim) {
   char* p;
   int i = 0;
   char** array;

   array = malloc(strlen(string) * sizeof (char*));
   p = strtok (string, delim);
   while (p != NULL) {
      array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) );
      array[i++] = p;
      p = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
  return array;
}
```

And then in `main`:

```
char s[128] = "Est2,2011,11,02,00,10,madrid,-3.467,44.3578,17.0";
char **array = split(s, ",");
int i = 0;
while (*array){
    printf("[%s]\n", *array++);
    i++;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that strings end with a '\0' as a delimiter which means an array arr with "a" in it is 2characters long (arr[0] is 'a', arr[1] is '\0'  You may want to write.

```
a = strlen(tokenPointer) + 1
```

also strncopy may be useful, it's strcopy with a third parameter which is length of string to copy.

It will save you looping through the string, and simplifying your function is probably valuable for you.

enrmarc is right that allocating memory dynamically is one way you might do it, you'd make a ragged array the exact size you need.  You could also call an array of pointers to strings IE char* stringArr[10] and then assign stringArr[0] to your first token and so on.  I'm going to assume that's not what you want.

Follow Michael Burr's advice, and also your function definition should probably look more like:

```
void writeToStrArrayOneByOne(char words[][], char sentence[])
```

Finally, debugging is hard, and I didn't exactly answer your question.  Make it easier with some Preprocessor Macros. try using the following:

```
#define PRINT_CVAL(a) printf(#a "contains %c\n", a)
```

you can change the C in CVAL and %c to I and %d for integers and so on, and it can help you know where in your program you having issues.